# repulsead in layout_with_fr

Tags: r, igraph

i upgraded recently from `igraph` 0.7 to `igraph` 1.0.
Due to the rewritten layouts the `layout_with_fr` is missing the `repulsead` and `area` options. I found these options VERY important as they allow to increase spacing between vertices, reduce vertex overlaps and better use the available space.

Is there anything equivalent in `igraph` 1.0? or can I somehow get back the old layout function? I don't see the point in removing useful features in a new release...

Comment: Did you try using `layout.fruchterman.reingold` directly? I think they are just deprecated in this release vs gone.

Comment: It is just an alias for the `layout_with_fr`( the code is `do_call(layout_with_fr, .args = c(list(...), params))`)

Comment: argh. you can pull the old igraph [from CRAN](https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/Archive/igraph/igraph_0.7.1.tar.gz), though it'll be a source build.